# SetState dynamicly to modify object values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

Hi Im trying to init my buttons state (setState) from a String that give you the key of the button(botones);

```
var stateButton = "button1-0"
```

[image]

**Actual State:**

[image]

**I don't now how write on react state the "state.botones[stateButton]: true" syntax**

Comment: Please don't post code as images. Post it as text or as a snippet if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to make a copy of the `botones` object with, for example, [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals):

```
setState({
  ...state,
  botones: {
    ...state.botones,
    [stateButton]: true
  }
})
```

If you're using a class component instead of a `useState` hook, you only need to specify `botones` as React will merge the state keys:

```
this.setState({
  botones: {
    ...this.state.botones,
    [stateButton]: true
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't modify the state object, because it must be treated as immutable. What you need to do is to define a new object containing the same content of the existing one, but changing only that button value.

Check: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state

*Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable.*

Answer (score 0):

```
this.setState({
 ...this.state
  botones: {
     ...this.state.botones, 
    [stateButton]: true
}});
```

I believe this should work

Comment: `this.state.botones[stateButton]` is not a valid object key. This will result in the same syntax error as before

Comment: I thought you were using class component but someone else posted the answer. Hope that solved your issue

Comment: It actually doesn't matter if its class or function. It's just not a valid object key

Comment: I made a minor mistake/typo I believe

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should not mutate state object. Instead you should use setState with prevState like

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
      user: {}
   }
}

this.setState((prevState) => {
     const updatedUser = {...prevState.user, [target.name]: target.value};
     return { user: updatedUser }; 
   }, () => this.doSomething(this.state.user);
);
```

[Source](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/handling-state-in-react-four-immutable-approaches-to-consider-d1f5c00249d5/)